# What is the proper way to use Slurm to run a Python file that calls a bunch of terminal commands on a HPC?

Tags: python, mpi, slurm, hpc, singularity-container

The HPC I am using requires me to run programs on the compute using Slurm. Currently I am locally running a Python script on my laptop that calls a bunch of bash commands in a loop. As an example, the Python file has a piece of code that looks like

```
command = "docker run -v %s:/usr/local/share/foo/ xyzw mpirun -n %d abcd %d /usr/local/share/foo/%s /usr/local/share/foo/%s" % (directory, numberOfCores, binaryPrecision, inFile, outFile)
command = shlex.split(command)
subprocess.call(command)
```

Here `xyzw` is the Docker container and `abcd` the program that I run using MPI. Now I would like to do something similar on the HPC but using Singularity and Slurm. My confusion is the following. Let's say I call the above Python file script.py. Then I have two options. I either keep the command inside the file as
`command = "singularity exec -v ..."` and run the Python file using `srun python3 script.py` or I change the command inside the file to `command = "srun singularity exec -v ..."` and run the Python file from the login node as `python3 script.py`.

Which of the two is the legal way of doing things? What I am worried the most about is that let's say I go with the option of `srun python3 script.py`. Then will the resources I allocate to the script be utilised efficiently or is it going to relegate the singularity stuff to a single core, hence making the whole exercise futile?

Comment: Singularity is not perfect when it comes to docker images. We had weird issues like this one https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/installation-on-a100-cluster/204973/4. So just test the singularity container locally.

Answer (score 1):

Processes run in singularity, unless specifically configured otherwise, have full access to the hardware resources of the host OS. How those resources are used is determined by whatever application is running inside the container.

MPI is its own special beast, so I *strongly* suggest reading through the Singularity docs on how to use it. It also directly addresses how to use it with Slurm.

- [SingularityCE and MPI applications](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.9/user-guide/mpi.html)